# Set byte[] to download as file

Tags: java, http-headers, jasper-reports, arrays, seam

I have a Jasper Report that generates an Excel file and outputs as a byte[], I want the file to appear as a download in the browser but at the moment it just prints the raw code to the browser.

The relevant part of the code is below, this is initiated from an AJAX request (the page has already been loaded):

```
    JasperReport jasperReport;
    JasperPrint jasperPrint;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();    

    byte[] excel = null;
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    try {
        ArrayList<SwimDataReport> dataList = getData();
        if(dataList!=null){
            JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList, false);

            jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportFile.getPath());
            jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, dataSource);
            JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
            ByteArrayOutputStream  xlsReport = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, xlsReport);            
            exporter.exportReport();
            excel = xlsReport.toByteArray();

            response.reset();
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Export.xls\"");

            xlsReport.close();

            OutputStream  ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            ouputStream.write(excel);
            ouputStream.close();

            facesContext.responseComplete();
            this.cleanUp();
        }else{
            return;
        }
    } catch (JRException e) {       
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you cannot download a file from an AJAX request, so I have used the h:commandButton to trigger the download instead.

Answer (score 0):

My working code similar to this has an uppercase D.

i.e.: `Content-Disposition` instead of `Content-disposition`.

This is also how [RFC2183](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) mandates.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Stefano, I tried it but it still just displays the raw code in the web-page

Answer (score 0):

Try using `a4j:htmlCommandLink` to fire the download request and give `target="_NEW"` in the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Content type for Excel files are:

for BIFF .xls file: ***application/vnd.ms-excel***

for Excel2007 and above .xlsx files: ***application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet***

Insted of:
"Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=**\"Export.xls\"**"

Try to use:
"Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=**Export.xls**"